# Select HasChildren in a table that has ParentID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Catalogs]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
    [Icon] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Order] INT NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] INT NULL,
    [CreatorID] INT NOT NULL,
    [LastModifierID] INT NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Now I want to select all catalogs with HasChildren column.

**Edit:** HasChildren will be generated at run time. If the row's ID does not available in ParentID column in all rows.

Comment: Where is the HasChildren column or do you want calculate it?

Comment: @Gidil, HasChildren is generated in runtime. For example, if the row ID does not available in ParentID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Catalogs] c WHERE c.ParentID = p.Id) 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChildren
FROM [dbo].[Catalogs] p
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT * , 
        HasChildren = CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  [dbo].[Catalogs] as child WHERE parent.[ID]=child.[ParentID])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM [dbo].[Catalogs] as  parent
```

Comment: In sub-query there should be `WHERE` instead `ON` ;)

Comment: @NenadZivkovic : Yes, it should be. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * , 
CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  Table1 as child 
WHERE parent.[ID]=child.[ParentID])>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AS HasChildren
FROM Table1 as  parent
```

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffd1a/17)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table with a hierarchy, where you want to query the rows that have children in the hierarchy, you should try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM   TABLE1 t1 
       INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 
               ON t2.PARENTID = t1.ID
```

Take a look at a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffd1a/5).

Comment: I need HasChildren, see update in question